# How do I get a jar task to include a single dependency in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have a task that looks like this (this is not the main jar this module kicks out, there is another one I can't show)

```
task interfaceJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'interface'

    from "$buildDir/classes/main/"

    include 'x/y/z/stuff.class'
}
```

And some dependencies like this

```
dependencies {
    /* lots of dependencies */
    compile 'com.esotericsoftware:kryo:3.0.3'
}
```

How can I include that one specific dependency in my interfaceJar task?

Comment: How would you like it be included? Jar into jar on unpacked content along your classes?

Comment: @Opal is there really a difference, usage wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include dependency jar without unpacking it first: (Note: if you use this, you may want to add a Class-Path entry to your manifest)

```
task interfaceJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'interface'

    from "$buildDir/classes/main/"
    from configurations.compile.findAll{it.name.contains('kryo')}

    include 'x/y/z/stuff.class'
    include '*.jar'
}
```

Edit: to unpack your dependency jar and include the contents in your interface jar:

```
task interfaceJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'interface'
    from("$buildDir/classes/main/"){
        include 'stuff.class'
    }

    configurations.compile.findAll{it.name.contains('kryo')}.each{
        from(it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it))
    }
}
```

Comment: How about unpacking it?